Number of incongruent triangles such that their side lengths are all integers and the sums of the lengths of two of their sides are equal to $2m+1$.
This is problem 9.72 from A path to combinatorics for undergraduates.
Let $n$ be the number of incongruent triangles such that their side lengths are all integers and the sums of the lengths of two of their sides are equal to $2m+1$ for positive integer $m$. Find $n$ in terms of $m$.
My attempt:
Define the following
$$A_{xy}=\{(x,y,z)|x,y,z\in \Bbb Z, 1\le x\le y\le z, x+y\gt z, x+y=2m+1\}$$
$$A_{yz}=\{(x,y,z)|x,y,z\in \Bbb Z, 1\le x\le y\le z, x+y\gt z, y+z=2m+1\}$$
$$A_{xz}=\{(x,y,z)|x,y,z\in \Bbb Z, 1\le x\le y\le z, x+y\gt z, x+z=2m+1\}$$
We have $n=|A_{xy}\cup A_{yz}\cup A_{xz}|$.
By the inclusion exclusion principle,
$$|A_{xy}\cup A_{yz}\cup A_{xz}|=|A_{xy}|+|A_{yz}|+|A_{xz}|-|A_{xy}\cap A_{yz}|-|A_{xy}\cap A_{xz}|-|A_{yz}\cap A_{xz}|+|A_{xy}\cap A_{yz}\cap A_{xz}|$$
Note that $A_{yz}\cap A_{xz}=A_{xy}\cap A_{yz}\cap A_{xz}=\{(x,y,z)|x,y,z\in \Bbb Z, x=y=z=\frac{2m+1}{3}\}$. So $|A_{xy}\cap A_{yz}|=|A_{xy}\cap A_{yz}\cap A_{xz}|$.
We calculate $|A_{xy}|$. Note that for any $(x,y,z)\in A_{xy}$, $(x,y)$ can only take the values $(1,2m),(2,2m-1),...,(m,m+1)$. If $(x,y)=(k,2m+1-k)$, then $2m+1-k\le z\lt 2m+1$ so $z$ can only take $k$ values. So $|A_{xy}|=\sum_{k=1}^mk=\frac{m(m+1)}{2}$.
We now calculate $|A_{xz}|$. Note that for any $(x,y,z)\in A_{xz}$, $(x,z)$ can take the values $(1,2m),(2,2m-1),...,(m,m+1)$. Suppose we are given $(x,z)=(k,2m+1-k)$. By triangle inequality, we have $y\gt z-x$. We have the following cases
Case $1$: Suppose $x\le z-x$. Then $y$ can only take the values of $z-x+1,z-x+2,...,z$, for a total of $x$ values. Note that in this case, by $x\le z-x$ and $x+z=2m=1$, we have $x\le \frac{2m+1}{3}$ or $x\le \lfloor \frac{2m+1}{3} \rfloor$.
Case $2$: Suppose $x\gt z-x$. Then $y$ can only take the values of $x,x+1,...,z$, for a total of $z-x+1=2m+2-2x$ values. Note that in this case, by $x\gt z-x$ and $x+z=2m=1$, we have $x\gt\frac{2m+1}{3}$ or $x\ge \lfloor \frac{2m+1}{3} \rfloor +1$.
Combining the above cases, we have $|A_{xz}|=\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor \frac{2m+1}{3} \rfloor}k+\sum_{\lfloor \frac{2m+1}{3} \rfloor+1}^m(2m+2-2k)=\frac{3l(l+1)}{2}+(m+1)m-(2m+2)l$, where we let $l=\lfloor \frac{2m+1}{3} \rfloor$.
We now calculate $|A_{yz}|$, Note that for any $(x,y,z)\in A_{yz}$, by the triangle inequality and the equality $y+z=2m+1$, we have $x\gt 2m+1-2y$. So given $(y,z)=(k,2m+1-k)$, $x$ can only take the values $2m+2-2k,2m+3-2k,...,k$, for a total of $3k-(2m+1)$ values. Note that $k\ge 2m+2-2k$ iff $k\ge \frac{2m+2}{3}$. So $|A_{yz}|=\sum_{k=\lceil \frac{2m+2}{3} \rceil}^m(3k-(2m+1))=3(\frac{m(m+1)}{2}-\frac{(r-1)r}{2})-(2m+1)(m-r+1)$, where we let $r=\lceil \frac{2m+2}{3} \rceil$.
We now calculate $|A_{xy}\cap A_{xz}|$. Note that for any $(x,y,z)\in A_{xy}\cap A_{xz}$, we have $y=z$, so $x+y\gt z$ is satisfied. Note that $(x,y)$ can only take the values $(1,2m),(2,2m-1),(3,2m-2),...,(m,m+1)$. So $A_{xy}\cap A_{xz}=\{(1,2m,2m),(2,2m-1,2m-1),(3,2m-2,2m-2),...,(m,m+1,m+1)\}$. So $|A_{xy}\cap A_{xz}|=m$.
We now calculate $|A_{yz}\cap A_{xz}|$. Note that for any $(x,y,z)\in A_{yz}\cap A_{xz}$, we have $x=y$, so $x+y\gt z$ iff $2y\gt z$. Since $y+z=2m+1$, we have $y\gt \frac{2m+1}{3}$ or $y\ge \lfloor \frac{2m+1}{3} \rfloor +1$. We also get $z\lt\frac{2(2m+1)}{3}$ or $z\le \lceil \frac{2(2m+1)}{3} \rceil +1$. So $A_{yz}\cap A_{xz}=\{(\lfloor \frac{2m+1}{3} \rfloor +1,\lfloor \frac{2m+1}{3} \rfloor +1,2m-\lfloor \frac{2m+1}{3} \rfloor ),(\lfloor \frac{2m+1}{3} \rfloor +2,\lfloor \frac{2m+1}{3} \rfloor +2,2m-\lfloor \frac{2m+1}{3} \rfloor -1),...,(2m-\lceil \frac{2(2m+1)}{3} \rceil,2m-\lceil \frac{2(2m+1)}{3} \rceil,\lceil \frac{2(2m+1)}{3} \rceil +1)\}$. So $|A_{yz}\cap A_{xz}|=(2m-\lceil \frac{2(2m+1)}{3} \rceil)-(\lfloor \frac{2m+1}{3} \rfloor +1)+1=2m-l-r$.
Combining the above, we have $n=\frac{m(m+1)}{2}+\frac{3l(l+1)}{2}+(m+1)m-(2m+2)l+3(\frac{m(m+1)}{2}-\frac{(r-1)r}{2})-(2m+1)(m-r+1)-m-(2m-l-r)=m^2-3m-1+\frac{3l^2}{2}+\frac{5l}{2}+\frac{5r}{2}-\frac{3r^2}{2}-(2m+2)l+(2m+1)r$
The problem is that I'm wondering if there is any way to simplify the result or a more clever way of doing the problem since the formula above look very messy.

While I admire how much you stuck with this, it seems overly complicated. I suggest the following: Fix $a \leq m$. How many values of $b$ satisfy $a, 2m+1 - a, b$ are sides of a triangle? What is the range of $b$? As we sum over all possibilities of $a$, is there any double counting? Why, or why not?

This solution is inspired by @Calvin Lin comment.
Fix an integer $a\le m$. Suppose we have some $b\in \Bbb Z$ such that $a,2m+1-a,b$ are the sides of a triangle. Since $a\le m$, one of the triangle inequality $b+(2m+1-a)\gt a$ is satisfied without any constraint on the value of $b$. By the other $2$ triangle inequality $a+(2m+1-a)\gt b$ and $a+b\gt 2m+1-a$, we obtain $2m+1\gt b\gt 2m+1-2a$, so $b$ can only take $2m-(2m+1-2a)=2a-1$ values. Note that different values of $a$ cannot generate the same triangle (Suppose $a_1$ and $a_2$ generate the triangles $a_1,2m+1-a_1,b_1$ and $a_2,2m+1-a_2,b_2$ such that the two triangles are the same. If $b_1\le m$, we have $2m+1-a_2=2m+1-a_1$ or $a_2=a_1$. If $b_1\gt m$, we have $a_2=a_1$.). So $n=\sum_{a=1}^m(2a-1)=m^2$.
